# Updating long list of IP descriptions with AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm running into quoting issues with AWS CLI when trying to update description of security group rules.

Can anyone advise how I can rewrite this piece to accommodate a list of IPs?

```
while read -r line; do
  aws ec2 update-security-group-rule-descriptions-ingress \
      --group-id sg-123456 \
      --region us-east-2 \
      --ip-permissions "[{'IpProtocol': 'tcp', 'FromPort': 443, 'ToPort': 443, 'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': ${line}, 'Description': 'Meaningful description'}]}]"
done < ip_list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to use this format:

```
while IFS=, read -r IP CLIENT_DESC
do
   aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --region us-east-2 --group-id sg-123456 --ip-permissions IpProtocol=tcp,FromPort=443,ToPort=443,IpRanges="[{CidrIp=${IP},Description=${CLIENT_DESC}}]"
done < server_rules
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the single quotes to encompass the whole  JSON, then use double quotes for the JSON content, which typically expects double quotes.

```
--ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": 443, "ToPort": 443, "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": ${line}, "Description": "Meaningful description"}]}]'
```

Comment: You can't put a single quote around a variable because it interprets as literal character. That's why I modified the syntax to use double quotes originally.